# Sculpting effects not showing until I switch to edit mode?

Tags: sculpting

I'm not very experienced with blender. I imported an .fbx-model and tried to sculpt in a few changes, but I can't see what I'm doing, because while in sculpt mode, it appears that nothing is changing at all. Only when I enter edit mode afterwards, the vertices get updated and I can see the effect. Please help!

Comment: Could you include a screenshot, if you can

Comment: Are you using the multiresolution modifier?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and was caused by joining 2 objects together which had shape keys, after removing the shape keys sculpt mode returned to normal.

Comment: Yay, had exact same problem, and this fixed it!